# With htaccess .. all url must be redirect to https with www

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

```
domain.com
www.domain.com/xyz
http://domain.com/xyz
http://www.domain.com/xyz
https://domain.com/xyz
```

must be redirect to below with .htaccess (apache 2.4)

```
https://www.domain.com/xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

**EDIT:** Testing using `curl` command line:

```
$> curl -I -k -A "Chrome" -L 'https://domain.com/'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 25 Jun 2014 06:50:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.domain.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 25 Jun 2014 06:51:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 13:16:20 GMT
ETag: "7ac-4fc302ecafc5e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1964
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: "https: //domain.com/" run this URL it will not redirect to "https:// www.domain.com/" (i put space here in url to show you exact example of url)... Can you please update this ?

Comment: With this rule `https: //domain.com/` will be redirected to `https: //www.domain.com/` because there is `[OR]` between 2 conditions. Make sure you test in a new browser and this is your very first rule.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. i did test with new browser and doing cache clear and another  person system. if url "http" and non www than it proper working because we have HTTP_HOST but url with "https" and non www than it is not working. is it ask for ssl confirmation for "proceed anyway" confirmation form. Only not working with "https". is there any more condition with RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\.  ?

Comment: This 2nd condition is `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.` which will trigger for URLs with non-www hosts.

Comment: yes sir, i got it is working with only "http" but it is not working with "https". thanks. We are almost near to done. Is there any more suggestion ? HTTPS_HOST ?

Comment: Again I tested this this rule and it works for `https://loccalhost/` also redirecting to `https://www.localhost/`. Most likely you have some other rule or code causing this problem for you.

Comment: Ohk ok sir.. I checked in 5 to 6 person's system it is not working may be it is because of linux system or else. I will try to clear chaching or elase.. Thanks a lot for your input sir

Comment: Besides `chrome` I have also tested it using command line `curl` and that output I am attaching in the answer above. (See edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `.htaccess` file in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(?:xyz/?)?$ https://www.domain.com/xyz [R=302,L]
```

If this works, you can change the `R=302` to `R=301`.

Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Hey there Kishan, following up on this, did one of the answers solve it for you, or is the question still there?

Comment: "https: //domain.com/" run this URL it will not redirect to "https:// www.domain.com/" (i put space here in url to show you exact example of url)... Can you please update this ? what i exactly want sir..

Comment: @KishanPatel I made a small tweak: added a question mark before the `$`. Let me know if that takes care of it. :)

Comment: Sir, Is it work if xyz would be dyanamic ?and if www not include than it will be add www even if it is with http or https ?

Comment: Your requirements are changing too much... Can't keep answering in the comments. If you ask another question, I will be happy to look at it—or someone else will. And to be effective answerers, we need feedback—have the answers by @anubhava and myself been helpful so far, or are we shooting in the dark?